# After Gitlab installation can't access gitlab page at VPS

Tags: gitlab, vps

I am trying to install Gitlab on my newly bought VPS(DigitalOcean, Ubuntu), but after the install and reconfigure, I can't get to the setup page of Gitlab. It's just showing the standard apache not found page. I have changed external_url to -> 'http://myip/gitlab'.

The errors I received after changing the url and reconfigure are below:

- Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]'
- Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[create gitlab database user]'
- Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[generate assets]'
- Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[unicorn]'
- Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[sidekiq]'
- Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[clear the gitlab-rails cache]'

The Lamp stack is installed, and some basic ufw firewall.
I have used the official Gitlab install/download guide:
https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#ubuntu1604

Comment: Are you using omnibus or are you building from source?

Comment: Omnibus, I guess. I followed the instructions from the link I posted :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `/gitlab` is actually not supported from a omnibus installation. You would need to host it on a (sub)domain.

There is however a way to enable this but it will require quite a significant amount of work to enable GitLab to work like you want. There is quite a extensive tutorial in the [GitLab Documentation](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/relative_url.html) so I recommend you check that out.

Comment: Well... I haven't tried your guide yet, but I change the external parth to the ip of the server(and also tried like gitlab.my-domain.com), but the same errors happens again. Starting to think something else is wrong, or that I might be missing something. I am getting: Chef Client failed

Comment: @simond Wait you have apache installed? You actually don't need it. Maybe therein lies the problem.

Comment: Yes I have apache installed. I installed Gitlab on the same server where all my domains are/serverside files. Is that wrong? I think the issue is (which you suggested) that my apache is overriding the git(landingpage)...

Comment: @simond Yes it is. GitLab comes with nginx. If you have apache you need to configure a reverse proxy as outlined [here](http://ryansechrest.com/2015/08/use-apache-instead-of-built-in-nginx-in-gitlab-ce/)

Comment: All right. I have followed your link. Now it's being installed and reconfiguring correctly, but I can't access the domain that I have setup. I assume that the virtual host file should be placed in: /etc/apache2/sites-available/gitlab.conf? Further more I have added the gitlab(as a subdomain) to the dns. Is that correct?

Comment: @simond In sites-available there should already be a file (probably something like 000-default). Edit that. Your DNS settings should be fine

Answer (score 0):

After 5 years, there happened a similar issue. since this one has no accepted answer besides being old, I have given an answer to it that seemingly solved the problem.

If someone finds this post, please check if that solves the issue: [installed gitlab on ubuntu shows apache default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683239/installed-gitlab-on-ubuntu-shows-apache-default-page/70711211#70711211)