# installed gitlab on ubuntu shows apache default page

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I installed gitlab on my vps from DigitalOcean using this command:
`sudo EXTERNAL_URL="http://gitlab.cc-soft.xyz" apt-get install gitlab-ee`.
When I go to `http://gitlab.cc-soft.xyz` it shows me this page:
[image]
how to fix this problem?

Comment: did you followed the instruction well? https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu

Comment: I followed the instruction exactly

Comment: not exactly it seems. have you checked for both `http://` and `https://` channels. gitlab seems to install for the second secure one, and you might be connecting to the first. `http` routes will listen on port 80 but `https` routes are on port 443 meaning apache will have two apps unless you forward everything to secure channel.

Comment: ok, not an issue of channels. your site is up currently and both will redirect to same apache page. i will check on a docker image.

Comment: I checked the errors using `sudo gitlab-ctl tail` and it shows me this: ` FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: I have made a long answer giving possibilities about why you see the apache welcome page instead of GitLab. that should solve your main problem. as for this error, it might simply be insufficient memory of your vps. I suggest you to check requirements.

Comment: for docker, I have used a 4GB WSL setup with 1GB swap on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the installation steps on an ubuntu docker container and gitlab runs with no problem. in case someone is interested:

```
docker run --name ubuntu-gitlab -p 8000:80 -p 8443:443 -it ubuntu:latest bash
```

---

Now about your problem. I can think of two possibilities:

- you have forgotten to set your DNS records for your gitlab machine and it currently points to another one running apache server.
- or you already have an web server installation in that machine.

In the latter case, you need to take one of these actions:

- remove current web server and install gitlab as the only one serving in that machine
- configure gitlab to use a relative url described in [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-a-relative-url-for-gitlab). you may need extra proxy setup in your main web server.

However, in my clear setup, i did not have another server and gitlab show the same first `404` page with the foxy (the one we get until gitlab get fully functional) in the main domain. it runs smooth in `http://domain/gitlab`

---

**PS:** not related to your issue, I will add a problem I faced and the solution I have found, for future referencing.

during the installation, I got a freeze (or maybe was taking too long):

```
ruby_block[wait for logrotate service socket] action run
```

and running the following in another shell seemed to work and it continued to the installation (`sudo` will be needed for non-root setup)

```
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/runsvdir-start
```